# Error en reloj checador

Tags: c#

disculpen tengo este condigo en un reloj checador, pero me da un error al momento de checar con la huella, ya lo cheque paso por paso, y resulta que me da un error en la conexión a la base de datos, despues de que hayan checado tres personas, como puedo resolver este error:

> Asistente para la depuración administrada 'DisconnectedContext': 'Error en la transición al contexto COM 0x157aa98 para este RuntimeCallableWrapper: No se puede hacer una llamada de salida desde la aplicación que está ejecutando una llamada sincrónica de entrada. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)). La causa más probable es que el contexto COM 0x157aa98 en el que este RuntimeCallableWrapper se creó se haya desconectado o esté ocupado haciendo cualquier otra cosa y no pueda procesar la transición de contexto. No se utilizará ningún proxy para resolver la solicitud en el componente COM y las llamadas se realizarán a dicho componente directamente. Esto puede ocasionar daños o pérdida de datos. Para evitar este problema, asegúrese de que todos los contextos, apartamentos y subprocesos se mantengan activos y estén disponibles para la transición de contexto hasta que la aplicación haya terminado completamente con el RuntimeCallableWrappers que representa a los componentes COM presentes en su interior.'

este es el codigo que uso:

```
        Boolean TerminarBucle = false;
        //MemoryStream stream;
        Template template1 = new Template();
        byte[] fingerprint1;
        int idEmpleado = 0;
        string NombreE;

        //if (Emp.Rows.Count <= 0) return;
        try
        {
            if (Emp.Rows.Count <= 0) return;

            DataTable empleados = Emp;

            foreach (DataRow item in empleados.Rows)
            {                    
                if (TerminarBucle == true) return;
                TerminarBucle = false;

                idEmpleado = Convert.ToInt32(item["IdEmpleado"].ToString());
                NombreE = item["Nombre"].ToString();
                fingerprint1 = (byte[])item["Huella"];

                template1.DeSerialize(fingerprint1);

                verificar1.Verify(FeatureSet, template1, ref resultado1);

                if (resultado1.Verified)
                {
                    pbFotoEmp.Image = publico.BytesAImagen((byte[])item["Fotografia"]);
                    lNombreEmp.Text = item["Nombre"].ToString();
                    lidEmp.Text = item["IdEmpleado"].ToString();
                    //MostrarDetalleAsistencias(idEmpleado);

                    DataTable BTA = biss.BuscarTipoAsistencia(idEmpleado);//cuando hago la consulta aqui
                    int TipoA = Convert.ToInt32(BTA.Rows[0]["TipoAsistencia"].ToString());
                    //verificamos si ya checo entrada y salida
                    if (TipoA == 1)
                    {
                        if (biss.VerificarUltimaAsistencia(idEmpleado))
                        {
                            biss.ChecarSalida(idEmpleado, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                            MessageBox.Show("La salida se ha checado", "Mensage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            biss.ChecarEntrada(idEmpleado, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                            MessageBox.Show("La entrada se ha checado", "Mensage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int RegistroA;
                        try
                        {
                            DataTable reg = biss.RegistroAsistencia(idEmpleado);
                            RegistroA = Convert.ToInt32(reg.Rows[0]["IdRegistro"]);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            RegistroA = 0;
                        }

                        if (RegistroA <= 0)
                        {
                            biss.InsertarAsistencia(idEmpleado);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            biss.ActualizarSalida(RegistroA, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                        }
                    }
                    TerminarBucle = true;
                    MostrarDetalleAsistencias(idEmpleado);

                }
                else
                {
                    TerminarBucle = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Algo malo paso " + ex.Message, "Advertencia de Seguridad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            TerminarBucle = true;
        }
```

Ya lo he tratado de resolver, pero sin llegar a la solución real.
La base de datos es en MySql.

Comment: En todo el codigo que pusiste, donde se supone que tenes problemas? yo no veo ninguna llamada a base de datos ahi. que se supone que es ese codigo?

Comment: ya puse un comentario en el codigo, cuando se hacer la consulta a la base de datos me arroja ese error en la variable que abre la conexion a la base de datos

Comment: Agrega el error y el codigo de conexion a bd que estas usando

Comment: ¿El stack trace? ¿El error es de la librería que lee la huella o de MySQL?

Comment: El mensaje de error hace referencia a un problema en una componente COM, o sea una libreria que no es .net, pero este mensaje no me cierra en el lugar del codigo que mencionas, de donde sale la variable `biss` ? que es lo que haces en esa funcionalidad

Comment: el proyecto lo estoy haciendo en tres capas, la variable biss hace referencia a la capa de negocio, que es donde hago la consulta sql